# References about a boolean function involving hamming weight

Tags: reference-request, hamming

Some weeks ago, I read an article about an interesting boolean function with some applications to cryptography. Then, I forgot about the article and now I cannot find it. Hence here I am asking if someone is familiar with this function and can give me some references. Thank you in advance.

Fix a positive integer $n$. The function boolean function $f$, taking a $n$bits words $\mathbf{x}$ as input and returning a single bit as output is defined by
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = x_{w(\mathbf{x}) \!\!\!\mod\!\! n} ,$$
where $w(\mathbf{x})$ is the Hamming weight of $\mathbf{x}$ (number of bits equal to 1) and $\mathbf{x} = x_0 x_1 \dots x_{n-1}$ (with $x_i \in \{0,1\}$).

Comment: isn't the mod n useless in the definition of f? w(x) will always be in {0 ... n-1} anyway.

Comment: @Geoffroy Couteau: the $\mod n$ is necessary to return $x_0$, rather than the undefined $x_n$, when each of the $n$ bits $x_i$ are $1$. An alternative is to define $x_n=1$ and then indeed $f(\mathbf{x})=x_{w(\mathbf{x})}$. Unfortunately that function does not ring any bell. Note: the function is balanced. It tends to return one of it's center bits.

Comment: Ah right, missed that, thanks (it does not ring any bell here either).

Answer (score 3):

It is the *hidden weighted bit function*. There is more than one paper related to cryptographic applications of this function, but the full definition may be found, for example, in Chapter 3 of this paper:

[Cryptographic properties of the hidden weighted bit function](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X14000146)